# Какой из мeтодов быстрее\лучше: echo или print

Tags: php

На чей стороне Вы? Почему Вы выбрали именно этот метод, чем он Вам больше угодил? А то я давно задаюсь вопросом, какой из этих методов быстрее\лучше.

Comment: Да пофиг. Когда на производительность начнут влиять такие вещи, то это будет значить, что я достиг Совершенства, я - Божество, и такие вопросы меня тем более не волнуют.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

print использует на один оп-код больше чем echo. Это совершенно ничто и никак не сказывается на скорости.

[ВОТ](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/8/print-vs-echo-which-one-is-faster) почитайте замечательную статейку.

Answer (score 0):

echo луче, потому что работает быстрее чем print и может принимать несколько аргументов.